# How to keep a variable in scope to all subroutines

Tags: perl

i am trying to create a module which is like this

```
package MyModule;

use strict;
use Exporter;
use vars qw($VERSION @ISA @EXPORT @EXPORT_OK %EXPORT_TAGS);

$VERSION = 1.00;
@ISA = qw(Exporter);
@EXPORT = qw(func1);

sub func1 {    
    my x = shift;    
    print x;    
    func2();    
}

sub func2 {    
    print x;    
}
```

and from a perl script, i am calling func1 of the module and passing a variable x. how do i make that variable visible to both subroutines or say all the functions inside that module. 
Please  help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Declare `$x` in the scope of the file using `my` or `our`:

```
my $x;

# subroutines definition
```

File has the largest lexical scope, so the variable will be visible for the rest of code (unless you re-declare it in some inner scope using `my`).

Comment: `our` is a somewhat funny thing, insofar is it is actually a lexical alias to a global variable.

Answer (score 3):

Make `$x` lexical to the <strike>package</strike> file rather than a single subroutine:

```
package MyModule;

use strict;
use Exporter;
use vars qw($VERSION @ISA @EXPORT @EXPORT_OK %EXPORT_TAGS);

$VERSION = 1.00;
@ISA = qw(Exporter);
@EXPORT = qw(func1);

my $x;

sub func1 {

    $x = shift;
    print $x;

    func2();
}

sub func2 {

    print $x;
}
```

---

But this example doesn't really make sense. A more sensible example would be to define a lexical filehandle that multiple subroutines within the package print to:

```
package PoorManLogger;

my $fileHandle;

sub initialize { open $fileHandle, '<', +shift }

sub alert { print $fileHandle 'ALERT: ', @_, "\n"; }

sub debug { print $fileHandle 'DEBUG: ', @_, "\n"; }

sub close { close $fileHandle; }  # Though this isn't technically needed.

1;
```

Comment: Lexicals have file and block scope. They aren't related to packages.

Comment: It’s more correct to say that **lexicals have scope** — which is a concept unrelated to packages — and that a scope is a file, a block, or an `eval` string. Another way to think of it is to equate scopes and blocks, but then you have to put imaginary curlies around files and `eval` strings.

Answer (score 2):

One of the main benefits of OO is encapsulation:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

package MyModule;

use strict; use warnings;

sub new {
    my $class = shift;
    bless { x => shift } => $class;
}

sub x {
    my $self = shift;
    $self->{x} = shift if @_;
    return $self->{x};
}

sub func2 {
    my $self = shift;
    print $self->x, "\n";
}

package main;

use strict; use warnings;

my $m = MyModule->new(5);

$m->func2;

$m->x(7);

$m->func2;
```

Comment: wouldn't `if (@_) {` work better than the `defined` test, catching the case of legitimately assigning `undef` to `x`

Comment: @Eric Of course. It's been a long time since I last wrote accessors.

Comment: Well, it’s an advantage if you want each object to have independent state. It’s a disadvantage if it complicates the code.  Using either file-scoped lexicals or regular old package variables is  more straightforward, and it does a reasonable job at providing class variables aka static data members. If you wind up making a private scope for common shared state between several functions, this can suffer from the straightforwardness troubles, since order of initialization can become a problem requiring an out-of-order execution block like `BEGIN{}` or `INIT{}` to solve.

Answer (score -1):

<strike>see [our](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/our.html)</strike>

(comments to my suggestion are correct, my suggestion wasn't)

Comment: That creates a variable that is visible outside the current file scope, which is more than what the OP asked for.

Comment: One could quibble over whether `our` actually *creates* a variable, rather than merely granting a view into the package. But I fear that would turn into some sort of deep ontological inquiry. ☹